# Cannot run executable from python using OS.system

Tags: python

I want to run a script from python that run as: `./cj 3 0.01 2 < matrix.txt` from terminal. When I use this in my code as: `os.system('./cj 80 0.01 2 < temp')`. It return status code 512. temp is the input to the c program just as matrix.txt

Comment: Looks like an error code returned by `cj` itself. And without knowing what `cj` actually is, it's a bit difficult to understand what's wrong

Comment: Presumably `cj` is an executable, not C code at all?  It may have been compiles _from_ C code, but you cannot run C code directly.

Comment: I have created the executable cj. If I run os.system('./cj 3 0.01 2 < matrix.txt') this return code 0 which means success. It is not working with temp

Comment: Again, this is a problem with how your executable works, not with python. What happens if you call your executable with the same parameters from the terminal and then you `echo $?`?

Comment: The command arguments and input redirection that you say work from the terminal differ from those in the `os.system()` call  - how can we know that is not the cause?  Can you run anything from `system()` successfully?  Have you tried the _failing_ command from the terminal?  Does your command return 512, returning a value does not mean it did not run, merely that it returned a value.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use subprocess module:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(["./cj", "80", "0.01", "2", "<", "temp"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
if process.returncode:
    print("Return code: %s STDERR: %s" % (process.returncode, stderr))
```

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca : It probably doesn't.  It should be posted as a comment suggestion rather thAn an answer perhaps.   It does give better I/O control and status information, so may be easier to debug any issues with the command.  The return value of `os.status()` is determined by the return value of the C library's `system()` function, which is platform and/or command shell dependent.  It could be the exit value of `cj` or it might not.

Comment: Subprocess module has more parameters as simple os.system so you can configure it how you want. Further more you can get the status code and handle it and you can check the STDERR. I think it is even more stable then os.system. On the other hand, if you get return code from your command then the problem is in your executable not in Python code.